# Why is my header defaulted at display: block?

Tags: html, css

So I have been working on a HTML file, and I just made my header. But for some reason whenever I open up the HTML file no elements will sit on the same line, its display property is defaulted at block. Here is my code:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
    <title> Squidward Tentacles</title> 
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="homepagecss.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="title">
    <h1> Your place for everything Squidward! </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id="header"> 
    <p> Home </p> <p> Chat </p> <p> Software </p> <p> News </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```html
#title{
 font-family: Verdana;
 text-align: center;
}

#header{
 border: 5px solid #fc6703;
 background-color: #fc6703;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: Verdana;
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
}
```

This is just to practice my HTML and CSS as I am a beginner with it, so please don't ask why I did it about Squidward. Anyway, it would be appreciated if you could tell me what is going on and what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` and `<p>` are block elements; the HTML/CSS spec says that they default to `display: block`.

Inline elements include `<span>` and `<a>`.

You can override any element by manually setting `display:` in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks said, the `<p>` element is displayed as block element as default causing it to display on a separate line.

Add this to your css to display it on the same line:

```
#header > p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```